# Question about asteriks and string concatenation in C++

Tags: c++, string

So I am currently going through Accelerated C++ course on udemy by Jeremy Siek and I was on that tutorial which he is mentioning string concatenation and in one part he gave task to print something (WITHOUT USING NESTED LOOPS) like this:

OUTPUT:

```
*
**
***
****
```

(- So I know about for loops from earlier and I am not completely new to C++ programming, but I am just complementing knowledge from earlier and I know that this problem can be solved with nested for loops. But THIS IS NOT MY QUESTION, KEEP READING, BECAUSE I HAVE TO MAKE INTRO INTO MY QUESTION)

Before he made program which is source code like this (WHICH I COMPLETE UNDERSTAND)

```
int main()
{
cout << "Please enter your name:";
string name;
cin>>name;

string greeting="Hello, " + name + "!";
string spaces(greeting.size(), ' ');
string stars(greeting.size(), '*');

cout << "**" stars << "**" << endl;
     << "* "<< spaces << " *"<< endl;
     << "* "<< greeting << " *"<< endl; 
     << "* "<< spaces << " *" <<endl;
     << "**" stars << "**" << endl;  

return 0;

}
```

Now, about my question:
I was trying to do that task he gave, and I came up with something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string star="*";
  int br=1;

  cout<<star<<endl;
  while(br<4)
  {
    br+=1;
    string (newstar.size(br, '*') );

    cout<<newstar<<endl;
  } 



  return 0;
}
```

Now, that program resulted error because of `string (newstar.size(br, '*') );` which I don't understand why is that wrong and why is `string newstar(br, '*');` correct 
without .size and without () ?

Comment: That's probably problem here, but I don't understand how did he do same thing in his code earlier ```string stars(greeting.size(), '*'); ```

Do you mean if I write something like this:
 ``` string newstar="Hello"; 
string kk(newstar.size(), '*'); ```
would be correct ?

Comment: please dont SHOUT. It is not nice to read

Comment: @idclev463035818 I am sorry for "SHOUTING" man, didn't mean to, it was just like something to pay attention to before writing any comments

Comment: you can still edit your question to remove the shouting. To emphasize text you can make it bold by surrounding it with *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your intention was to have:

```
 string newstar(br, '*');
```

istead of:

```
string (newstar.size(br, '*') );
```

also maybe increment br after that line, and you could remove 'cout << star << endl;'

See the fill constructor: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

Comment: Yeah, my idea was kind of different on beginning I wanted to have that number, but I thought I could somehow access that int variable...
It's inexplicably now, my ideas are crazy...

Answer (score 0):

The error is

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:14:13: error: 'newstar' was not declared in this scope
     string (newstar.size(br, '*') );
             ^~~~~~~
prog.cc:14:13: note: suggested alternative: 'star'
     string (newstar.size(br, '*') );
             ^~~~~~~
             star
```

Because you did not declare `newstar`. The compiler already stops there, but there is more wrong: `std::string::size` takes no paramters and it is not clear what you expect from writing `string ( some_number);`.

As I dont really understand the logic of your code I cannot offer you a complete fix, but I can give a hint. This:

```
std::cout << std::string(4,'*');
```

constructs a `std::string` consisting of 4 copies of the character `*` and prints that on the console.

Comment: My idea was a bit different and it really make nonsense because with that method .size I wanted to take size of int type of variable, and that actually mixed in my head and it actually made the whole problem. 
I thought I can, you know do something like ```br++;``` and to take size of it and put it in as parametar, which obviously wouldn't work !